# Is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ the smallest countably generated $\sigma$-algebra containing the singletons?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Note that the singletons generate the countable-cocountable $\sigma$-algebra, which isn't countably generated.

We can ask this question in general for Polish spaces. Of course, this doesn't hold generically for all topological spaces e.g., an uncountable space with the discrete topology.

**EDIT**: I should make this question more precise. The notion of a "smallest" countably generated $\sigma$-algebra containing a given $\sigma$-algebra is ill-defined, since the intersection of countably generated $\sigma$-algebras needn't be countably generated. What I actually mean to ask is whether there exists a countably generated strict sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ containing the singletons.

Comment: @K.Power Perfect! I guess we can close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Yup I guess we can! Good question regardless though. Took me a while to find that linked answer, although I knew I had seen it before.